# If you have multiple variables with different values and i want to pass these values through a block of code that process the value,how do i do that?

Tags: c#

This is a hypothetical scenario, but lets say that

```
int age1 = 12, age2=3, age3=7
```

I want to pass each of these variable to through a block of code that tells me whether or not it the age is greater then 10.

Is there a way to do that without loops and writing a whole bunch of if statements. (If I have to write 1 if statement that is fine, but not multiple ones)

Comment: Do you want to know whether each one separately is greater than 10, or whether every one of them is, or whether *at least* one of them is? You should have an array of ages `var ages = new [] { 12, 3, 7 };`, and you need to learn about loops and functions. Since you're making such a big secret of what you're really trying to do here, nobody can tell you how to do it. "Pass them through a block of code that process the value" may mean something very specific to you, but to me that phrase could describe an infinity of different programs.

Answer (score 1):

As a generalized solution, you can try `params` and *Linq* (`Any`):

```
 static bool HasGreaterThan10(params int[] ages) {
   return ages.Any(age => age > 10);
 }
```

Example

```
if (HasGreaterThan10(12, 3, 7)) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to test if *all* the ages are greater then `10` use `All`:

```
static bool AllGreaterThan10(params int[] ages) {
   return ages.All(age => age > 10);
}

...

if (AllGreaterThan10(age1, age2, age3, age4)) {
  ...
}
```

You can declare the array locally and get rid of method if you want:

```
if (new int[] {age1, age2, age3}.Any(age => age > 10)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: why this variable name containing " then"  ?

Comment: @edelwater: I'm sorry for my *misspelling*

Comment: :) i thought you referred to the OP's SIC spelling :)

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called **[arrays](http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/csharp-array.htm)**.

And looping over an array is always preferred over writing code that names things a1, a2, a3, ... and that then explicitly deals with all those values.

The point is: maybe you *think* that those values will do today, but thing is: there is a certain chance that you will have to use 4 values tomorrow. And 7 the other week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "or else" operator (`||`)

```
bool isGreater(int age1,  int age2, int age3) {
  return (age1>10) || (age2>10) || (age3>10);
}
```